# RabbitMQ management plugin presents a blank page

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an issue regarding the RabbitMQ management plugin. I've done a clean installation of RabbitMQ service, and everything is up and running. I've enabled the management plugin and the output seems to be ok. The issue is that when I go to http://localhost:15672 I get a blank page, titled by "RabbitMQ Management" and with its favicon. I'm using Google Chrome.

Looking at the console, it seems that it couldn't find the .js files that mentioned in index.html file, even though that they DO exist in the folder it says they are...

I tried to find related issues but couldn't find any similar problems in Chrome. Any ideas, anyone?

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the console messages. thanks.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clear cache in chrome? Other browser?

Comment: @Gabriele which version of what? RabbitMQ? it's 3.6.1.

Comment: @cantSleepNow there is NO other browser than Chrome ;). How do I clear cache?

Comment: @DanielY settings clear cache or something like that, just google it

Comment: @cantSleepNow it includes clearing data, history and passwords, I wouldn't like that...I'll download Firefox and update

Comment: @cantSleepNow same issue with Firefox, too

Comment: @DanielY there are a few known situations for this problem. 
Please attach the javascript console debug `view->developer->javascript console` abd reload the page. And also the screenshot.

Comment: @Gabriele see edited post

Comment: @DanielY it would be great follow your problem. It is the first time I see this error. Can you add more information as OS (linux, windows) and share the server logs ? Thank you.

Comment: I ran across this issue before in IE. The company I was working for had crazy harsh security settings on its servers and it wouldnt allow javascript to run. Removing that setting helped me

Comment: @chris.ellis I also try to do it from my company's pc, which has crazy harsh security settings, but it worked to me before, but recently I formatted my pc and re-installed RabbitMQ and there's this issue since.

Comment: @Gabriele I use windows 7, how can I provide you with more info?

Comment: YOu should have the logs here `C:\Users\{youruser}\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log`